# Verify that all set values of an enum are distinct

Tags: c, enums, compilation

I just recently found out that when setting values of variables of an enum, several variables can have the same value. For example, the following code is perfectly correct:

```
enum my_enum
{
    A = 3,
    B = 4,
    C = 3,
    D = 5
};
```

However, in my framework, I **have** to set manualy each variable, since it is used to communicate error codes to other systems. I cannot change the value of an error code without asking for the other teams to modify it as well.

I regrouped all error codes into an enumeration to be sure we do not reuse the same error code for different reasons (which was the case before). But now, nothing stops anyone to reuse the same value for different errors.

Is there a way I can make the compiler return an error if I assign the same value to different names in my enum?

I can compile with either gcc or clang.

Comment: You could write a unit-test that checks the uniqueness of all _integer values_ in a given enumeration.

Comment: The best thing you can probably do is to not specify explicitly the values, except for the first.

Answer (score 2):

A `switch` statement cannot have two cases with the same value. So you can have a switch somewhere. Make it with no `default:` case and gcc will warn you that a member of the enum is not handled in the switch statement if you add a new value. If two values of the enum are the same, compilation will fail.

Some examples:

```
typedef enum {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_SAME = 0
} err_t;

volatile err_t e = ERR_NONE;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    switch( e )
    {
        case ERR_NONE:
        break;

        case ERR_SAME:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with `gcc -Wall switch.c` gives:

```
switch.c: In function 'main':
switch.c:16:9: error: duplicate case value
     case ERR_SAME:
     ^
switch.c:13:9: error: previously used here
     case ERR_NONE:
     ^
```

and...

```
typedef enum {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_NEXT,
    ERR_MISSING,
} err_t;

volatile err_t e = ERR_NONE;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    switch( e )
    {
        case ERR_NONE:
        break;

        case ERR_NEXT:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with `gcc -Wall switch-missing.c` gives:

```
switch-missing.c: In function 'main':
switch-missing.c:12:5: warning: enumeration value 'ERR_MISSING' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
 switch( e )
 ^
```

Comment: That's nice, I didn't knew about duplicate case warning on switch. I guess I could do a unittest that do a switch on all values, but that would make me duplicate code, and I will need a really nice comment to be sure no one adds a default: Thanks for that answer anyway!

Comment: Just put it in your code. You'll get the warning - even if the code is thrown away by the linker because it's not used.

Comment: @DainDwarf warning should read error in your comment. Code compilation will fail if there is a duplicate case in the switch and warn if an entry in the ENUM and not present in the switch

Comment: You can use a macro to generate both the enum and a function with the switch, however, in C, the macro's syntax will not be very nice. I think you will ultimately have to do something like `ENUM(Type, (Name0, Value0), (Name1, Value1))`, etc. If it is at all possible for you to use C++, you can get nicer syntax like `ENUM(Type, Name0 = Value0, Name1 = Value1)`. If you are interested, search SO for "enum to string" to get some ideas on how to get started. I might also be able to throw together a little example if this kind of approach is acceptable for your project.